# Crear un trapezio pero que se le pueda dar box-shadow

Tags: html, css

he conseguido crear un trapecio en css pero usando `border` y cuando le añado box shadow no se me aplica bien, hay alguna manera sencilla de hacer un trapezio y que se le pueda dar box-shadow? Tambien esta el hecho de que el texto al darle absolute ya no se me centra solo

```css
.trapezoider {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60%;
    height: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    border-right: 3em solid transparent;
    border-left: 3em solid transparent;
    border-top: 3em solid rgba(0,0,0);
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px rgba(3, 1, 32, 0.3);
}




#bronze{
    color:rgba(176,141,87);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    right: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoider">
   <span id="bronze">Bronce</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Creando toro trapecio por debajo si le haces el box-shadow no te lo aplica a la transofrmacion que le has echo al div.

Comment: no entiendo bien lo que me quieres decir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me refiero a esto, tienes que crear un contenedor, poner tu trapezoide normal donde lo quieres y lo pones en posición absolute, después creas otro igual y lo pones debajo para que sea la sombra.

```css
.contenedortrapezoider{
  position : relative;
}

.sombratrapezoider{
    width: 600px;
    height: 0px;
    border-right: 3em solid transparent;
    border-left: 3em solid transparent;
    border-top: 3em solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    opacity:.5;
    filter: blur(2px)
}

.trapezoider {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 600px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    border-right: 3em solid transparent;
    border-left: 3em solid transparent;
    border-top: 3em solid rgba(0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    margin-top:0px;
}




#bronze{
    color:rgba(176,141,87);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    right: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedortrapezoider">
  <div class="sombratrapezoider"></div>
  <div class="trapezoider">
     <span id="bronze">Bronce</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wua esta es como la forma manual de hacerla no? Porque no hay ninguna manera de hacerle con box shadow o algo asi no? modificando solo la caja en vez de los bordes? los svg tambiene tienen forma caja o?

Comment: Esque estas transformando los borders del div pero el div siempre es una caja por lo tanto a la que pones el box-shadow te lo ara siempre en la caja